# Ghost white space below featured image in Wordpess template

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

I am new to creating Wordpress templates (I'm primarily a front-end developer), and I've created a template that shows the featured image. For whatever reason, it displays white space below the image. The margin and padding is set to 0, so this is a big mystery to me. Here's my template code:

```
echo '<div class="featured-image">';
the_post_thumbnail();
echo '</div>';
```

And here's what it's showing:
[Image with white space below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKmfn.jpg)

If you can see the site, here it is: https://staging.orangesocks.org/this-is-my-story/

Comment: This is not a PHP problem, it's just HTML/CSS. Provide the HTML code that's generated by PHP, and relevant stylesheet rules.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Because an image is inline element, it was adding white space below. Adding display:block to the image fixed the issue.